# Why isn't my bash 4.1.2 package vulnerable to shellshock? Is my test wrong?

Tags: bash, shell, shellshock-bash-bug

My Bash shell version is GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

I tested shellshock bug by using below command

```
x='() { :;}; echo VULNERABLE' bash -c :.
```

It was not printed  VULNERABLE message back.

I have read that the bug exist up to bash version 4.3 ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1H12rMdLTg )

what could be the reason.

Comment: Almost all distros released out-of-band patches. Just because it wasn't fixed *upstream* until 4.3 doesn't mean that your distro are a bunch of incompetents.

Comment: ...if your OS is genuinely Red Hat, they had a patch out within days. Not one fully compatible with the final version's environment variable format for exported functions, but a working patch nonetheless.

Comment: "GNU/Linux" is a generic name for *all* operating systems combining a Linux kernel and a GNU userland. Red Hat is only one of the many, many distributions following this pattern. Which is to say, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: All distributions -- Red Hat, Arch, Debian, Ubuntu, all of them -- apply patches to their packages, making them slightly different from what upstream releases. That's where their added value comes from -- they're providing a set of packages tested to work well together, with patches for compatibility issues, security bugs, etc.

Comment: BTW, I'm inclined to argue that this isn't really a question about software development. Perhaps [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate? But wherever you ask it, be sure to provide your distro name and package version.

Comment: Why the distro name and package is important here , this is the bug of Bash right?

Comment: but it's your distro that's packaging bash, and part of packaging is applying patches. So bash-as-distributed-by-Ubuntu or bash-as-distributed-by-Red-Hat are all a little bit different from upstream bash.

Comment: for instance, `/dev/tcp` is actually turned off by default in upstream bash (requires a compile-time flag to turn it on), but it probably works for you, right? That's something your distro did when they were building the package.

Comment: Yeah , Got it . Thanks a lot Charles :)

Answer (score 2):

Updated packages with patches backported to the locally-supported version of bash were released for major distros within days of shellshock being identified. (Indeed, they were released in rather a hurry, and the interim fixes often used a different environment variable format for exported functions than what the final releases do, meaning that a function exported in one version of the shell often won't be recognized by another running as a subprocess).

Just because *upstream* didn't have a final patch merged doesn't mean your operating system or distribution didn't push a backport -- indeed, it would be wildly irresponsible for them not to.